# What can I remove after install of Drupal 7

Tags: 7, installation

What files and folders can I remove after I have installed Drupal 7
My installation uses SQLite
In order to make the total package as small as possible I have removed unused themes from the root themes directory but what else can I remove?
Can I remove modules from te root modules directory that I will not be using e.g. Aggregator, Forums etc?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, yes if it's not enabled you can remove it... but why? You're not really saving a lot of space.

Comment: I agree; plus, the same operation should be done every time a new release of Drupal is copied.

Comment: Simpletest alone is over 3mb - do I need it? My installation is currently about 20mb. It is a simple one purpose site and doesn't require Aggregator, Forums etc etc. I am aware that I would need to repeat the process with each new release but that would only be for security releases.If Drupal is a framework then why not tailor it to my needs and remove the functionality I don't need?

Comment: @Ludwig Updating Drupal is not just done for security releases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! But...before removing any modules, follow certain precaution steps first (backup, disable modules).

Please see http://drupal.org/node/250783 on more information on uninstalling modules.

One thing I would also consider is to remove or at least lock http access to all *.txt files in the main D7 installation folder for security purposes.

Comment: I know that I can create a backup and then progressively remove module, stop & restart MAMP etc I was hoping to find out if there were any of the core modules that just can't be removed, e.g.  field, field-ui must remain.  Thanks for the note on the txt files.